# SQL SAVE DATATIME

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table with a `Date` type. And I want to insert the date in this format: `dd-mm-yyyy` (ex: 27/10/2014). I already tried with String but the problem is when i want do a search with 2 Dates the SQL just compare the days. I just realy need the day, month and year. And in C# i use DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(); to retrieve the date and insert in the database.

I used that query to search the dates:

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE ([COLUMN] >= '25/10/2014' AND [COLUMN] <= '26/10/2014');
```

Its any way to save the data like the format i want? Then will be more easy to select the data I want.

Sorry for my english, please help thanks.

Comment: Is your username just ironic, or are you really trying to stick it to the folks at Stack Overflow by recreating a banned account?

Comment: ***What*** concrete database? SQL is just the **query language** - but not a **database product**. Please add a tag for what **database product** you're using!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never ever save your date and datetime values as strings. And always parameterize your SQL. If you want to make it easy for yourself, use a [micro-ORM like Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) to simplify such operations:

```
var result = connection.Query(
    "SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE where data between @lower and @upper", 
    new { lower = DateTime.Parse("10/25/14"), upper = DateTime.Parse("10/26/14") });
```

I also recommend you use concrete data types o return information from the database, so you will not be forced to use dynamic properties.

Comment: if i put in this format dd-mm-yyyy (27/10/2014) will work too?

Comment: Yes, as long as you use the correct FormatProvider. If you want to be real specific, use ParseExact.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server doesn't store a `DateTime` in any string format - it's stored as an 8 byte numerical value.

The various settings (language, date format) only influence how the `DateTime` is shown to you in SQL Server Management Studio - or how it is parsed when you attempt to convert a string to a `DateTime`.

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use DATE if you only need the date portion, and DATETIME2(n) when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the DATETIME datatype if ever possible

So in your concrete case, I would rewrite that query as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE ([COLUMN] >= '20141025' AND [COLUMN] <= '20141026');
```

to be independent of any language, regional or dateformat settings in SQL Server ....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for example in MS SQL, you can save the data in [datetime2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) (or equivalent) and format it on the way out. This approach will allow you to compare the dates.

**Steps you can take:**

1. change the Data type for the column at hand from string to datatime
2. You can apply formatting on the date upon retrieving. For example, users from Europe will have different date structure from users in north America.

Comment: ***IF*** he's using SQL Server **2008** or newer - `datetime2` isn't present before the 2008 release ...

Comment: @marc_s, true revised